# Do I have to flag answer or question in review?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, review-suspension

Today I receive a review ban saying

> Many of your recent reviews have been unhelpful. For example: [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17081038) should've been edited and flagged as "not an answer". [This](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17081267) should've been edited and flagged as needing to be closed

But for first answer, I add a comment and say link only answer is not recommended. Second question, I downvote the question and upvote the first comment which asks op to learn basic Python.

So do I have to flag the question or answer otherwise my review will be seen as incorrect?

---

I don't think my question is a duplicate . Because I just want to know more about **flag** specifically but the other question asks how to review which is a more **generic and broad** question relating to flag, skip and many other things.

Comment: The goal of these review queues is to *identify* problematic content and *handle* it. You didn't handle it. You kicked the can down the road. A comment doesn't solve the problem. If you see a question or answer in these review queues that can be fixed by editing, then you need to edit it. If you see one that violates our guidelines and *cannot* be fixed by editing, then you need to flag it. Leave comments when you need to ask for clarification or have a *minor* suggestion, not when there are irredeemable quality problems. I think the dupe adequately answers your questions; follow its advice.

Comment: Keep in mind that questions in most review queues are shown only to a limited number of people, so if you do an incomplete review, then you are actually hurting the site by helping bad content stick around.  Either review it completely or don't review

Answer (score 7):

Absolutely yes! The whole point of the review queues to channel questions / answers based on certain criteria to the community. If a question / answer needs to be closed or deleted, then you need to use the appropriate flag or close vote regardless whether you see it in a review queue or "in the wild".

Answer (score 2):

If a post is not appropriate for this site, you should flag it appropriately.

Downvoting is a different signal that's more of an "I don't like this", doesn't lead to the question being removed ([except when it does](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that)) and should thus not be taken as an alternative to flagging.

Upvoting or leaving a comment is to help the user understand what's wrong with their post, but that doesn't mean they'll actually fix it.

For the sake of site quality, it's better to assume the user won't fix their post and take the appropriate action (if the user does fix it, there are ways to restore their post, such as the reopen queue or asking on Meta).