# What would have been the correct action in a Late Answer review to not get a ban?

Tags: support, review-queues

I got a review ban for [this](https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17122157) Late Answer review.

The answer I was supposed to review was obviously off topic, badly formatted and written in hardly understandable English.

There was already a very well written comment by another SO user, informing the user who wrote the answer that his post was off topic and pointing him to http://stackoverflow.com/tour.

I thought, well, I have nothing to add to this, so I up voted the comment and clicked "I'm done". Sometime later I got a review ban for this as http://stackoverflow.com/review informed me.

I'm not complaining, I'd just like to understand better what my mistake was to avoid making it again. Should I have down voted the answer? Should I have taken another/additional action?

I already read the explanation about triaging, but I can't find a similarly detailed explanation for reviewing Late Answers (hopefully not because I'm the only one on the planet who is too dense to get it intuitively).

Comment: Which review was it?

Comment: Can we see that answer? False positives can happen. Related: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/303795/i-do-not-understand-why-i-failed-this-audit

Comment: Here's the review, but the answer in question was deleted in the meantime: https://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/17122157

Comment: For future reference, the same crazy nutter who drafted the Triage FAQ wrote [something for Late Answers first](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/288505/how-should-i-get-started-reviewing-late-answers-and-first-posts/288506#288506).

Comment: @anothernode That review wasn't an audit, so you'd have been manually banned by a moderator if that's actually the post that banned you. What did their message say?

Comment: Exactly the same situation as [this guy](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/355365/). You obviously did not know that you were supposed to ***flag*** problematic posts when reviewing them. Although the explanatory text accompanying review bans is very limited, it did explain that, while that was posted as an answer, it was actually another question entirely. Things like that need to be flagged as "not an answer" so that they can be removed. And, as the message concluded, *"It seems you are new to reviewing, so this is a short ban."* Thanks for asking where you were unsure!

Comment: All right, that helps a lot, thanks!!