# Review ban on first post, which doesnt appear in reviewed item list

Tags: support, review-audits, review-suspension

I got a review ban on this post: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17206742

Now I obviously agree that this is something that doesn't belong on SO. However, it appears that I haven't reviewed it at all. My review list looks like this: [image]

I do however think I stumbled across this post, and possibly also downvoting it. However, I never got to see the "you failed this audit" screen. So am I retroactively banned, and is the action I did mysteriously removed from my activity?

Comment: You did review it, but the post is deleted so it doesn't appear in *that* list. It appears here: https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=1481116 (only visible to you and moderators).

Comment: It was deleted like 1 minute after you reviewed it

Comment: I confirmed gnat's duplicate suggestion, because it tells you in an easy-to-parse format how to handle the FP queue. Had you followed that advice, you'd not have missed that post.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You were manually banned by a moderator; the post was not an audit:

> You reviewed https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/17206742 incorrectly. At the very least, you should have flagged this as needing to be closed (unclear, opinion-based, too broad, anything really would have worked). It also looks pretty clearly like spam, so that flag would have been appropriate, too. You apparently did nothing... Please pay more attention to each review in the future.

The reviews list in your profile only lists posts that are not deleted. You can find *all* your reviews by going to the [*my review history* link](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history?userId=1481116) (link target only visible to you and moderators) at the bottom of the [review queue history page](https://stackoverflow.com/review/first-posts/history).

The post was flagged as spam by other users, and when a moderator confirmed the flags they also checked if anyone had let the post slip through review.

Reviewing your review, I see that the recorded action is 'reviewed', so I'm going to assume you *did* take action, and downvoted as you stated:

> Luuklag reviewed this 1 hour ago: Reviewed

I'm lifting your review ban, **this time**. However, you do need to pay more attention to your reviews, this wasn't your first review ban.

For clarity, the post was:

> [image: spam post screenshot]

The link leads to a commercial software developer pitching their mobile app development wares.

Even without the link, such a question **at the very least** off topic and should be closed. A downvote is a rather weak reaction to this post. Next time, do vote / flag to close such a blatantly off-topic post. And once you checked the link, it should have been reasonably obvious this was spam.

Comment: Point taken. Now wait 10 minutes to accept an answer ;)

Comment: _You apparently did nothing..._  - Does it mean that the OP clicked "skip"?

Comment: @AlonEitan: I think this may be a case of misreading the review action. I'm talking to the moderator in question.

Comment: I'm assuming the post was quite obviously spam? Otherwise seems kinda harsh for one wrong review imo.

Comment: @George: it's a *little* borderline. We do need users to pay attention to this kind of deception, however.

Comment: Even if you couldn't tell it was spam, the post was quite obviously in need of closure, @George. A downvote alone isn't sufficient here. Also, just gonna leave [this](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/355774/add-an-obvious-flag-button-to-the-late-answers-and-first-posts-review-queues) here...

Comment: @Alon No, not skip. The First Posts and Late Answers review queues say "Reviewed" when you click the blue "I'm Done" button. By itself, this doesn't tell us what the reviewer actually did, but moderators can see whether or not you raised a flag. In this case, no flag was raised. The only thing we *can't* see is if someone downvoted (because votes are anonymous), so that's the only thing that Luuklag could have possibly done. The moderator who wrote that message just forgot about downvoting as a possibility. Still, though, as stated above, downvoting a post like this isn't sufficient in review.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, thanks for lifting the ban. And yes I agree my course of action should have been better, was just triggered by the great amount of downvotes to downvote it and let it be roomba'd. Whilst raising a flag was obviously the best course of action.

Comment: @Luuklag Roomba takes a while. We'd prefer that garbage be deleted from the site as quickly as possible, *especially* questions, because they push out other questions that deserve an answer. Don't worry about "piling on" flags. It never causes any problems, and can actually speed up the process in some cases. (That said, always feel free to downvote, if you feel it's appropriate!)